# Uploading +100MB files via FTP with connection break ups

Tags: ftp

I'm trying to upload one larger file to a web server - using CUTEftp Professional + VOIP Internet connection via Wi-Fi. File size is 136MB (it is a video).

It breaks up over and over. At some point it stops uploading and starts again from beginning.

Anyway, any ideas, suggestion about any upload manager, software which I can use due to these circumstances?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try free FileZilla instead of CuteFTP? It supports upload resume. Just search FTP Client Upload Resume in google and you'll find a lot of other FTP clients. But I personally suggest FileZilla, it supports upload resume feature. If upload breaks in middle, it will continue.